# Robolectric different threads in Android Studio vs. Gradle tests

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, gradle, junit, robolectric

why are thread names different when I start a Robolectric test from Android Studio vs. the Gradle build?

e.g. consider this simple test:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class RobolectricRxThreadTest {
    @Test
    public void testMainThreadName() {
        assertEquals("main", Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

when I start this test

- directly in **Android Studio** (by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>) the test is **okay**
- but when I start the **gradle tests** (e.g. from the Gradle projects view: `:app` - `Tasks` - `verification` - `test`, or from the Terminal view: `./gradlew test`) it **fails**.
  The thread name is `Thread worker` and not `main` as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I just reproduced the issue, but I wonder why do you need this test?

If you really want to check main thread then the correct way would be:

```
 assertThat(Thread.currentThread()).isEqualTo(Looper.getMainLooper().getThread());
```

And this test pass from AS and console both runs.

Comment: I don't need this test - it was just for explanation. I really wonder why the thread of the main looper is not called `main`. This is confusing (at least for beginners, like me)

Comment: The thread name comes from the test runner I suppose. So it doesn't have relation with Robolectric